# ¿Cómo mostrar en la página principal las vistas de mi modelo desde otra App en Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Muy buenas tardes tengo el problema siguiente..
 tengo una app principal ahí esta el base.html además el home.html, contacto.html y otros más....

En ese mismo proyecto tengo otra app 'Noticias' aquí tengo noticias.html y detalleNoticias.html...

Primeramente tengo mi estructura de html en el base.html dentro de eso hay un

```
 {% block content%}
 {% endblock%}
```

Y aquí llamo las páginas como Home, noticias, contacto y otros más y me muestra su contenido de cada uno.
Como sabrán en el Home se muestra de todo un poco como página principal.. y en ese home.html en una sección de la página me gustaría mostrar al menos 2 noticias.. estaba intentando hacer lo mismo que hice en 
noticias.html

```
{% for post in posts %}

<img src="{{post.image.url}}" alt="image">
<h2 class="title-post"><a href="#">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
<p>{{post.content}}</p>

{% endfor %}
```

Pero en el Home.html no me muestra nada.. de que manera podría llamar para mostrar algunas noticias aquí???
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Crear una vista a parte para el home sería una solución donde puedas desplegar las noticias dentro del template home, lamentablemente Django no permite hacer más de un render para una misma vista.

Por lo mismo en un archivo views.py poner algo como lo siguiente:

(Debes de reemplazar por tu información correspondiente)

```
def home(request):
    noticia = Noticia.objects.all()
    contexto = {'noticias':noticia}
    return render (request, 'index/home.html', contexto)
```

donde :

- home : es el nombre de la vista
- noticia : es la variable que toma cada una de las noticias traída por la consulta `Noticia.objects.all()`
- Noticia : es el nombre de tu modelo noticia
- contexto : es la información que se envía al template para que este lo use.

Después de esto solo te queda llamar a esta información como ya lo estas haciendo en el template home

Saludos!

Comment: si crearia una nueva app por ejemplo galeria y de esta app tambien desearia mostrar unas 5 imagenes en el home .html  debo hacer el mismo procedimiento?.. es es mi Views de mi appPrincipal                 from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
 return render(request, "principal/home.html")

def about(request):
 return render(request, "principal/about.html")

def noti(request):
 return render(request, "principal/noticia.html")                                 def contact(request):
 return render(request, "principal/contacto.html")

Comment: En el caso de una galería no se debería crear una app nueva, simplemente llamar a esas imágenes como archivos estáticos bastaría :)

Comment: no se que paso .. pero aun no me muestra nada

Comment: (request, 'index/home.html', contexto) hace un llamado al template, donde index es la carpeta donde está el template llamado home, quizás tu template está en otra carpeta o lo tienes en la carpeta static

Comment: def home(request):
    noticia = Post.objects.all()
    contexto = {'noticias':noticia} ------- aqui noticias es el nombre de mi App?
    return render (request, 'principal/home.html', contexto)

Comment: noticias en una especie de array que se crea para almacenar tus noticias

Comment: ademas de esto en el Views le he importado de esta manera.  from noticias.models import Post

Comment: Debes de importar el modelo de tus noticias
from noticias.models import Noticias, donde Noticias es el nombre de tu modelo

Comment: la aplicacion se llamama noticias y mi modelo se llama Post y asi se muestra  from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from noticias.models import Post

Comment: Entonces si Post y en la consulta Post.objects.all()

Comment: asi se muestra mi Views de la app Principal

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from noticias.models import Post

# Create your views here.

Comment: def home(request):
    noticia = Post.objects.all()
    contexto = {'noticias':noticia}
    return render (request, 'principal/home.html', contexto)

Comment: def about(request):
 return render(request, "principal/about.html")

def noti(request):
 return render(request, "principal/noticia.html") 

def contact(request):
 return render(request, "principal/contacto.html")

Comment: Como tienes distribuidas tus plantillas? Estan sueltas en tu carpeta templates o estan subdivididas en subcarpetas?

Comment: En el caso del template no seria for post in post si no, for noticia in noticias

Answer (score 0):

Para que no haya confusiones, te lo explicare de manera general usando un nombre de modelo *X*, si quieres mostrar ciertas cosas de tu modelo *X*.

Simplemente basta hacerlo como en cualquier otra, esto varia dependiendo de si usas Class Based Views o Views basadas en funciones te explicare el funcionamiento tanto en una como en otra.

Si usas Class Based Views te quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
class Home(ListView):
    template_name = 'La dirección de tu template'
    model = *X*
```

Si usas Views basadas en funciones te quedaría así:

```
def home(request):
    x_list = *X*.objects.all()
    template_name = 'Dirección de tu template'
    context_dict = {'X_List': x_list} 
    return render(request, template_name, context_dict)
```

En tu template:

```
{% block content %}
    Tu contenido aparte :IDK SKEREEE!
{% for x in x_list|slice:":2" %}
  Aquí tu html que utilizaras y por si no lo sabes,
  los campos de los modelos se llevan así:
      {{ X.campo }}
{% endfor %}
```

{% endblock %}

Una buena practica, que es muy facil llevar acabo es separar zonas pequeñas y cambiantes de tu codigo en includes, los cuales introduces en tu template con:

```
{% include 'Direccion de tu include' %}
```

De esta manera llevaras un control mucho mejor de estos, un saludo.